# Could someone please provide a solution to part A of a rates of change question

Tags: related-rates

Rates of change question from a mathematics textbook about a dissolving pill.

Having a hard time understanding the working and thought process of part (a) of the question. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxJpK.png

Comment: Think about $\frac{dV}{dr}$ and the chain rule for (a).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the help Paul - good hint. I think I got the answer using chain rule: dr/dt = dr/dV * dV/dt which will give k.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the welcome José. I will be sure to do this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to differentiate the volume $V(t)$ wrt. $t$ and compare with the formula for the surface:

- $V(t)=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3(t) \Rightarrow \frac{dV}{dt}= 4\pi r^2(t)\cdot \dot r(t)$
- $S(t) = 4\pi r^2(t) \stackrel{\frac{dV}{dt}=kS(t)}{\Longrightarrow}$
  $$k\cdot 4\pi r^2(t) = 4\pi r^2(t)\cdot \dot r(t)\Leftrightarrow \boxed{\dot r(t) =k}$$

Comment: Thank you for your worked solution. Very clear and concise - it makes sense now.

Comment: You are welcome. :-)